# How to add created at and updated at column and update it on values save?

Tags: magento2, model, db-schema

I want to add created_at and updated_at columns in a custom table and update both columns on saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to update the created_at and update_at columns on saving the data in the table.

1. Create created_at and update_at columns in the database table.

`.................
<column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Creation Time"/>
<column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_at" on_update="true" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Update Time"/>
.................`

2. Update the Model/CustomTable.php file to add `beforeSave()` function.

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
class CustomTable extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    private $dateTime;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        parent::__construct(....);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data to be saved to database.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        parent::beforeSave();
        if ($this->isObjectNew() && !$this->getCreatedAt()) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($this->dateTime->formatDate(true));
        }
        $this->setUpdatedAt($this->dateTime->formatDate(true));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.